# Function not finding an argument when vectorized in R?

Tags: r, function, vectorization

I'm wondering why my vectorized function below works fine when I use `cii(peta = c(.3, .4), N = 120, df1 = 3, df2 = 116)` BUT when I use `cii(F.value = c(30, 40), N = 120, df1 = 3, df2 = 116)` the function gives `"peta" is missing`?

**P.S.** I have made it clear in my function that when `F.value` is `NA`, function should use `peta` and ELSE use `F.value`. But why I'm getting the `"peta" is missing` error?

```
cii <- function(peta, F.value = NA, N, df1, df2, conf.level = .9){ # Upper-Level FUNCTION

 ci <- Vectorize(function(peta, F.value, N, df1, df2, conf.level){ # Lower-Level FUNCTION

options(warn = -1) 
q = ifelse(is.na(F.value), (-peta * df2) / ((peta * df1) - df1), F.value) 
alpha = (1 - conf.level)/2

f <- function (ncp, alpha, q, df1, df2) {
abs(suppressWarnings(pf(q = q, df1 = df1, df2 = df2, ncp, lower.tail = FALSE)) - alpha)}

I <- sapply(c(alpha, 1-alpha), function(x) optimize(f, interval = c(-30, 30), alpha = x, q = q, df1 = df1, df2 = df2)[[1]])

round(data.frame(lower = I[1], upper = I[2], conf.level = conf.level, F.value = q), 6)
})  

data.frame(t(ci(peta = peta, F.value = F.value, N = N, df1 = df1, df2 = df2, conf.level = conf.level)))
}
 ### TWO EXAMPLES OF USE: ###
cii(F.value = c(30, 40), N = 120, df1 = 3, df2 = 116) # Gives Error!!!
cii(peta = c(.3, .4), N = 120, df1 = 3, df2 = 116)    # Works Fine !!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `cii()` expects there to be an input for the `peta` argument, and you are not providing one. You have a few options:

#### 1. Call cii() with peta = NA

`cii(peta = NA, F.value = c(30, 40), N = 120, df1 = 3, df2 = 116)`

```
# Output:
     lower    upper conf.level F.value
1 29.99996 29.99996        0.9      30
2 29.99996 29.99996        0.9      40
```

#### 2. Re-write cii() to assign a default value to peta

e.g.
`cii <- function(peta = c(.3, .4), F.value = NA, N, df1, df2, conf.level = .9){ ... }`

```
cii(F.value = c(30, 40), N = 120, df1 = 3, df2 = 116)

# Output
     lower    upper conf.level F.value
1 29.99996 29.99996        0.9      30
2 29.99996 29.99996        0.9      40
```

*As for this case:*

`cii(peta = c(.3, .4), N = 120, df1 = 3, df2 = 116)`

You don't get an error because in your function you've already assigned a default value of `NA` to `F.value`.

Answer (score 0):

BTW although Marcus's solution works - your error occurs **because you are using `Vectorize`**

You can call a function with a single argument if the second argument is not required for evaluation

```
myfun <- function(a, b) {
    ifelse(a==1, print(a), print(b))
    if (a==1) { print(a) } else { print(b) }
}
myfun(1)
# [1] 1
# [1] 1
myfun(2)
# Error in print(b) : argument "b" is missing, with no default
```

This is also true for a nested(?) (internal) function

```
myfun <- function(a, b) {
    internalfun <- function(a, b) { ifelse(a==3, print(a), print(b)) }
    if (a == 1) { print(a) } else { print(b) }
    internalfun(a = 3)
}
myfun(1)
# [1] 1
# [1] 3
# [1] 3
# BTW, I do not understand why `3` is printed twice
```

This still works when you explicitly name the arguments when calling the nested function

```
myfun <- function(a, b) {
    internalfun <- function(a, b) { ifelse(a==3, print(a), print(b)) }
    if (a == 1) { print(a) } else { print(b) }
    internalfun(a = 3, b = b)
}
myfun(1)
# [1] 1
# [1] 3
# [1] 3
```

But it fails when using `Vectorize`

```
myfun <- function(a, b) {
    internalfun <- Vectorize(function(a, b) { ifelse(a==3, print(a), print(b)) })
    if (a == 1) { print(a) } else { print(b) }
    internalfun(a = 3, b = b)
}
myfun(1)
# [1] 1
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument "b" is missing, with no default
```

My guess is that when vectorizing your function, `Vectorize` has to 'evaluate' your arguments, which is leading to the error